# Bootstrap 3.3.7 nav is dropped down by default on mobile via Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 in Wordpress and the mobile menu is dropped down by default. Any help would be appreciated.

I've already checked for more than one instance of Bootstrap but can't see if there's something I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
       <div class="container-fluid">
           <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="nav-logo" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/eclipse-acu.jpg" class="logo img-responsive" alt="Eclipse Acupuncture"/></a>
           </div>

           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

              <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array (

                        'theme_location'            =>  'primary',
                        'container'                 =>      'nav',
                        'container_class'           =>      'collapse, navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'         =>    'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class'                =>      'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                        'fallback_cb'          =>      'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'                   =>   new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()

                    ) );
                ?>

       </div>
       <!-- /.container-fluid -->
   </nav>
```

Comment: Can you share the link to the site where this is happening?

Comment: do you want toggle menu on mobile?

Comment: I can't share the link, I'm working on it locally unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, the menu should toggle when the button is clicked on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit!

The line reading:
    'container_class'           =>      'collapse, navbar-collapse'

Should instead read:
    'container_class'           =>      'collapse navbar-collapse'

Removing the comma fixed the issue.